# RevitAPI C#: How to undock DockablePane onStart

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am attempting to do up a custom `dockablePane` and I was able to produce one successfully. However, my current implementation seems to `show` and dock the `dockablePane` `onStart`, which is not what I want. I want to `show` the pane only upon tapping on the `ribbonButton`.

My current implementation as such:

```
//Application onStart
namespace DockablePane
{
    public class SetupLaunchPane : IExternalApplication
    {
        Result IExternalApplication.OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        Result IExternalApplication.OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            //Create a ribbon panel at the top
            RibbonPanel ribbonPanel = application.CreateRibbonPanel("Dockable Pane");

            //Get url to the DockablePane.dll
            string assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            //Create a push button and add to ribbon panel
            PushButtonData buttonData = new PushButtonData("launchPane", "Launch Pane", assemblyPath, "DockablePane.LaunchPane");
            PushButton pushButton = ribbonPanel.AddItem(buttonData) as PushButton;

            //Register dockable pane
            application.ControlledApplication.ApplicationInitialized += RegLaunchPane;

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        private void RegLaunchPane(object sender, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.ApplicationInitializedEventArgs e)
        {
            var registerPaneCommand = new RegisterDockablePaneManager();
            registerPaneCommand.Execute(new UIApplication(sender as Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application));
        }
    }
}

//Show the dockable pane on button pressed
namespace DockablePane
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Regeneration(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.RegenerationOption.Manual)]

    public class LaunchPane : IExternalCommand
    {
        Result IExternalCommand.Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {

            var dpid = new DockablePaneId(DockablePaneIdentifierManager.GetPanelIdentifier());
            var dp = commandData.Application.GetDockablePane(dpid);
            dp.Show();

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

    }
}

//Registering the dockable pane
namespace DockablePane
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Regeneration(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.RegenerationOption.Manual)]

    class RegisterDockablePaneManager : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            return Execute(commandData.Application);
        }

        public Result Execute(UIApplication application)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = new DockablePaneProviderData();
                var pane = new ViewPane();
                data.FrameworkElement = pane as FrameworkElement;

                var dpid = new DockablePaneId(DockablePaneIdentifierManager.GetPanelIdentifier());
                application.RegisterDockablePane(dpid, "Pane", pane as IDockablePaneProvider);
                return Result.Succeeded;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                return Result.Failed;
            }

        }
    }
}

//At ViewPane.xaml.cs
namespace DockablePane
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ViewPane.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ViewPane : Page, IDisposable, IDockablePaneProvider
    {
        public ViewPane()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

        public void SetupDockablePane(DockablePaneProviderData data)
        {
            data.FrameworkElement = this as FrameworkElement;
            data.InitialState = new DockablePaneState
            {
                DockPosition = DockPosition.Right
            };
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, at `onStart` I am only registering the `dockablePane` and has not called `show`, but it appears docked on the right when Revit launches. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside  public void SetupDockablePane(DockablePaneProviderData data)

```html
data.VisibleByDefault = false;
```